# Using REG Query to find and delete Registry Keys

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry

I am working on a batch file to remove all aspects of a antivirus software. I have a .bat built that will uninstall the program and delete the residual folder associated with it.

My problem is the Reg Keys left behind. I have built into my .bat a set of REG Query commands to find the keys but cant figure out how to delete them using the output. There are a lot and any way I could automate the search and delete would be great. We are going to deploy this .bat with a network tool to remove this virus protection so we can install a different product company wide.

How can I use my .bat to not only find the keys but delete them?

Here is what I have so far:

```
echo off

wmic product where name="VIPRE Business Agent" call uninstall

REM Clean up phase

RD /s /q "C:\Program Files (x86)\VIPRE Business Agent"

REG Query HKU /f "VIPRE" /s > "C:\Users\eddies\Desktop\out.txt"

REG Query HKLM /f "VIPRE" /s > "C:\Users\eddies\Desktop\out2.txt"

REG Query HKCU /f "VIPRE" /s > "C:\Users\eddies\Desktop\out3.txt"
```

Comment: Just delete them. There is no need to see if they exist. Keys aren't randomly in the registry. They are at set locations.

Comment: @Noodles That's what I want to do. The problem I am having is they aren't all in the same location. Depending on how old the machine is and how many version upgrades its had, there can be keys scattered all over the place. I don't care so much about the finding part as being able to take what I find and delete it automatically.